# In how many ways $N=2^6\cdot3^4\cdot5^6$ can be written as a a product of two numbers that are even?

Tags: combinatorics, factoring

$N=2^6*3^4*5^6=A*B$

In how many ways N can be written as a product of two numbers that are even?

$N=2A*2B$

then how $2^4*3^4*5^6=a*b$? and why not $2^6*3^4*5^6=a*b$

---

With the expression $2^4*3^4*5^6=a*b$ the number of factors was computed as $5\times 5\times 7=175$. Then the number of pairs was calculated as $\frac {175-1}2+1=88$. How does this calculation make sense?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question $A,B$ and $a,b$ are both ambiguously defined and are likely confusing you.

If $$N=2^6\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^6=A\cdot B$$ is the product of even factors, we can write$A=2a, B=2b$ so that $$N=2a\cdot 2b$$ and we have $$a\cdot b=2^4\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^6=\frac A2\cdot \frac B2=\frac N4$$

---

There are then $175$ factors. One of these is the square root and the others come in pairs $p\cdot q=\frac N4$. So if we want the number of pairs, we take off one for the square root, and have $\frac {174}2=87$ pairs (here we are counting the factorisation $p\cdot q$ as being the same as $q\cdot p$). To get all the factorisations we add back the one which involves the square root - this being $p^2$ involves just one of the $175$ factors - and obtain the answer $88$.

Comment: There will be one way when a and b both will be equal. How @MarkBennet

Comment: So you get the number of factors of $a\cdot b$ as $5\times 5\times 7=175$. One of these is the square root, the other factorisations come with pairs of factors. How you count depends on whether you count $pq$ as being the same as $qp$ or whether the order of factors matters.

Comment: For example in case of 16 ...ordered pair of factors are (8,2) (2,8) (1,16)  (16,1) (4,4). I want to know why are we subtracting 175 from 1. Just because two numbers are equal? @MarkBennet

Comment: How it makes sense? @MarkBennet. I am trying to visualize it by an example but still I am stuck

Comment: @SakuziMarkel If you could edit your question to show exactly what calculation has been done in which $1$ has been subtracted, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Number of factors came out to be 175. Then in the solution it has been written since a and b are equal, hence subtract 175-1=174. Now number of ordered pairs will be 174/2=87+1=88 @MarkBennet

Comment: @SakuziMarkel I have edited the question and my answer - the question should contain all the information so that other people have a chance of answering it. In your case with $16$, if you count factorisations as the same if they involve the same numbers whatever the order there are three. $3=\frac{5-1}2+1$ where subtracting and adding $1$ both reflect the factor $(4,4)$, which takes up just one of the factors $1,2,4,8,16$. The calculation here is dealing with unordered pairs.

Comment: Thankyou so much @MarkBennet. Next time I will ask question properly